# Smooth, multi-color gradients?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, gradient

I've browsed around and can't find what I'm looking for. I am experienced in Photoshop and Illustrator both to a certain degree, but would prefer something in Illustrator (scaling vector image).

How do you go about designing and creating such a smooth gradient as in the following image? Are there any tools or methods for helping with color selection? Also, the subtle "blocking" or "sectioning" throughout where there a little slice of similar, but different colors? Just looking for an overall methodology in the design and creation of these commonly popular designs.

Bonus: Anyone seen any HTML5- or CSS-only implementations?

Thanks as always, geniuses!

[image: Example smooth gradient.]

Comment: I would recommend you look into the Crystallize and Mosaic filters in photoshop, located under `Filters -> Pixelate`

Comment: @Johannes, that is a fantastic solution that I never even thought of attempting. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### 1. Draw a gradient.

[image]

---

#### 2. Convert it to a smart object.

---

#### 3. Apply `Filter` → `Pixelate` → `Crystallise`.

[image]

---

#### 4. Add a `Gradient Map` adjustment layer on top

[image]

---

#### 5. You can now adjust the `Crystallise` values, if you’d like.

[image]

---

Sure, it’s not using HTML or CSS, but the technique does use a gradient map. Gradient maps are the best.

[image]

Please note that this example could have been built many ways. It could have just been a bitmap layer with a gradient, then the filter applied. That would give the same result, but not allow for easy editing later. The gradient map was used for precise control and flexibility.

Answer (score 0):

I ran across this resource: http://williamngan.github.io/kubist/
It's a web app that generates cubist-like artwork in SVG format. Reading the creator's "How it works" article is also quite fascinating. While this is not a direct answer to your question, it does provide some ideas on how to accomplish the smooth "mosaic"-like gradient effect you're looking for. And,as the Kubist web app demonstrates, it can be done in HTML with the use of SVG graphics.

Answer (score 0):

I've used an app called Dmesh http://dmesh.thedofl.com/ for creating very custom triangulation gradients and images. Its a free app for windows and mac (and iphone). Launch the app and drag and drop any image onto it and wherever you click it will form a vertices. You can then export the final image as a SVG and open it up in illustrator for further editing. Great tool!